# Запопление текстового поля при нажатии клавиш на клавиатуре

Tags: javascript, html, input

Проблема состоит в том что есть текстовое поле, изначально пустое. При нажатии кнопки с клавиатуры к примеру "Q" в поле должно вставлятся значение 1, а при нажатии "E" значение -1. Получилось только вставка одного значения при нажатии мышкой по созданному button'у. Как привязать вставку значения value кнопкам с клавиатуры. В гугле искал решений не найдено. реализовать не могу

```
  <html>
  <HEAD>
    <script language="JavaScript">
     function but1() {
     document.getElementById("pole").value = "data"}
    </script>
   </HEAD>

    <body>

<form action="0">
  <input id="pole" type="text" name="name1"> 
  <input type="button" name="name" value="Кнопка" onclick="but1()">   
</form>
```

Comment: А что мешает использовать keyup, keydown, keypress - https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Comment: Посмотрите здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878983/capture-key-press-without-placing-an-input-element-on-the-page и здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('input').keypress(function(event){
   var code = event.keyCode | event.witch;
    if(code == 81 || code == 113){
        $(this).val('1');
    }else if(code == 69 || code == 101){
        $(this).val('-1');
    }
   return false;
});`